# I can't change the default Python version from Apple supplied 2.7.2 to 3.2.2 (OS10.7)

Tags: python, macos

in Lion, have installed python 3.2.2 from python.org. It comes with a terminal command that is supposed to move this version of python earlier by updating my shell profile. When i run it, and then check my default python in Terminal, it still says 2.7.2 which is the Apple supplied one.

Do I need to run the command with sudo to get it to change the default python to 3.2.2?

I've also tried the VERSIONER method but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not returning any sort of error or output or anything?

Comment: First of all, it's only a one character difference. If you're looking to prevent that extra character, why not save even more characters by creating a symbolic link named `py` or heck, even `p`?

Comment: Also note that 2.7.2 is not the Apple-supplied one; the only 2.7 version supplied-to-date by Apple is 2.7.1 with OS X 10.7.  The 2.7.2 is likely also a python.org version you installed.

Comment: thanks Ned, sorry my mistake, I should have said 2.7.1, not 2.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 3 interpreters, you must enter `python3` not `python`.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.2
$ python3 -V
Python 3.2.2
```

For more background on the current recommendation that `python` refer to a version of Python 2 and `python3` refer to a version of Python 3, see the draft [PEP 394 - The "python" Command on Unix-Like Systems](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: So you're saying you can't change the system default `python` to a version of Python 3?

Comment: On OS X, Apple does not supply a Python 3 - yet - so there is no system default option for Python 3.  The `VERSIONER`* defaults and env variables are an Apple-supplied extension to their Pythons. The python.org distributions for Python 3 on OS X follow the recommended practice of providing a `python3` link for all Python 3 versions.  You could, of course, make your own symlink in `/usr/local/bin` or elsewhere but not in `/usr/bin/` as Apple's `/usr/bin/python` is not a symlink.

Comment: @agf: Do NOT try.  Numerous parts of OS's and applications depend on specific versions being available.  In some cases, as the default.  iLife, for example, expects Python 2.6.  The "default" Python was (and continues to be) a bad idea.  Always name a specific version.

Comment: @S.Lott I know. The question was asked hoping someone would add that kind of info to the answer.

Comment: @agf: What?  Why don't you simply provide the actual facts as a comment?  Why play games writing a rhetorical question?

Comment: @S.Lott I'm not playing games; I'm not using OSX and was trying to get Ned, or someone else actually using OSX, to provide more details about the issue.

Comment: The issue is not specific to OS X.  AFAIK, the only exception to the recommendation to using `python3` is the Arch Linux distribution and that decision has been rather controversial and caused problems for their users.  Some day the default for `python` may change to Python 3 but the consensus in the Python community is that it is not time to do that yet.

Comment: See, for example, the as-yet unapproved draft PEP 394:  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Comment: thanks for the info about entering python3, when I do that Terminal does show 3.2.2. As it is, I'm using that version with IDLE, so I don't really HAVE to try to change the "default". I'll try the suggestion of making my own symlink, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfamiliar with osX, but as several system applications might depend on a certain python version, it might be a bad idea to swap the default.

One alternative that might suite your needs is to use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew), it allows you to have several python versions side by side and lets you set a default version on a user to user basis, *without* having to meddle with your system python, among other things. It is the equivalent of RVM for those who are familiar with ruby, or a sort of virtualenv for python interpreters. One big advantage is that it allows you to easily install and use the exact python versions you need independently from what is available in your operating system.

Some examples:

Install a python interpreter:

```
pythonbrew install 2.7.2
```

Permanently use the specified python (for current user):

```
pythonbrew switch 2.7.2 
pythonbrew switch 3.2
```

Use the specified python in current shell:

```
pythonbrew use 2.7.2
```

Runs a named python file against specified and/or all pythons:

```
pythonbrew py test.py
pythonbrew py -v test.py # Show verbose output
pythonbrew py -p 2.7.2 -p 3.2 test.py # Use the specified pythons
```

The only downside of pythonbrew, is the need of a compiler and header files, and that an install can take a bit of time, as it compiles from source.

Comment: The OP already has several versions installed.  In fact, Apple ships recent versions of OS X with multiple versions of Python installed.

Comment: pythonbrew does a little bit more than just install different pythons, I have added some examples from the docs to illustrate. It makes it easier, for example, when you want to test your app against several 2.x/3.x versions, or set a certain version to a default, (which is a bit more complicated if you have more than one 2.x version),and from the information I have does exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I'm familiar with `pythonbrew`. It has nice features.  However, on Mac OS X, Python is typically built and installed as what is known as a framework build. Each Python version has its own isolated `bin` and `lib` and `site-package` directories so nearly all of the benefits of `pythonbrew` and `virtualenv` are provided out of the box.